# Consuming a custom salesforce REST API from Zendesk

Tags: oauth, salesforce, zendesk, zendesk-api

I want to consume my salesforce REST API from ZENDESK app. To consume my salesforce REST API i need to send Authorization header with salesforce acess_token. To get the access token in zendesk i am creating a server side zendesk application. I writing code to fetch the access token and deploying in on my other server and finally using that site in my zendesk app.
Is my approach correct or is there any better approach?

Comment: Does the Salesforce access_token change, or once generated is it static?

Comment: Access_token is oauth token. It has an expiration time after which the token becomes invalid. By default expiration time is 1 min. You can also set the expiration time while creating oauth app. After token is expired you have to ask for new token which is different. So it is not static.

Comment: as far as I know the Zendesk Apps Framework does not have a native way to handle Refresh tokens, so I think your approach is the best.  Build a simple server side application that can handle obtaining and using the refresh token.